Compute the norm of a bilinear operator on the space of Lipschitz functions vanishing at $0$
Let $M=[-1,1]\subset ℝ$. A function $f: M → ℝ$ is a Lipschitz function if there exists a finite non-negative constant $C$ such that $|f(s)-f(t)| ⩽ C\|s-t\|$ for all $s, t ∈ M$. Denote the set of Lipschitz functions on $M$ by $Λ(M)$.
For $f ∈ Λ(M)$ let
$$
\|f\|_{\text{Lip}}=\inf \{C:|f(s)-f(t)| ⩽ C\|s-t\| \text{ for all } s, t ∈ M\} .
$$
Then $\|⋅\|_{\text{Lip}}$ is a norm on $X$, where
$$
X=\{f ∈ Λ(M): f(0)=0\} .
$$
Let $T: X → \mathcal{B}(X)$ be defined by: Let $h$ be a fixed element of $X$.
Let $T(h): X → X$ be defined by: for $f ∈ X$,
$$
\left(T(h) f\right)(s)= \begin{cases}\|s\|^{-1} h(s) f(s) & \text{ if } s ≠ 0, \\ 0 & \text{ if } s=0 .\end{cases}
$$
I want to compute $\|T\|$.

Some thoughts:
Fix $h ∈ X$. Let $f ∈ X$. By definition of $X$, $f(0)=0\implies\left(T(h) f\right)(0)=0$. To show that $T(h) f$ is Lipschitz, we require to show there exists $C$ such that
$$
\left|\left(T(h) f\right)(s)-\left(T(h) f\right)(t)\right| ⩽ C\|s-t\|   \text { for all } s, t ∈ M .
$$
If $s=t=0$ this holds for any $C$.
If $s ≠ 0$ and $t=0$ then, since $f$ is Lipschitz,
$$
\left|\left(T(h) f\right)(s)-\left(T(h) f\right)(t)\right|=\left|\frac{1}{\|s\|} h(s) f(s)\right| ⩽\|h\|_{\text{Lip}}\|f\|_{\text{Lip}}\|s\|=\|h\|_{\text{Lip}}\|f\|_{\text{Lip}}\|s-0\| .
$$
Case $s=0$ and $t ≠ 0$ works likewise.
Now let $s, t ∈ M$ with $s ≠ 0, t ≠ 0$. Then, using $f(0)=h(0)=0$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left|\left(T(h) f\right)(s)-\left(T(h) f\right)(t)\right|\\
& =\left|\frac{1}{\|s\|} h(s) f(s)-\frac{1}{\|t\|} h(t) f(t)\right| \\
& =\left|\frac{1}{\|s\|}(h(s)-h(0))(f(s)-f(t))+\left(\frac{1}{\|s\|}-\frac{1}{\|t\|}\right) h(s) f(t)+\frac{1}{\|t\|}(h(s)-h(t))(f(t)-f(0))\right| \\
&\small ⩽\left|\frac{1}{\|s\|}(h(s)-h(0))(f(s)-f(t))\right|+\left|\left(\frac{1}{\|s\|}-\frac{1}{\|t\|}\right) h(s) f(t)\right|+\left|\frac{1}{\|t\|}(h(s)-h(t))(f(t)-f(0))\right|\\
& ⩽ \|h\|_{\text{Lip}}\|f\|_{\text{Lip}}\|s-t\|+\|h\|_{\text{Lip}}\|f\|_{\text{Lip}}\left|\|s\|-\|t\|\right|+\|h\|_{\text{Lip}}\|f\|_{\text{Lip}}\|s-t\|\\
&\text{By Reverse Triangle Inequality, }\left|\|s\|-\|t\|\right|\le\|s-t\|,\\
& ⩽ 3\|h\|_{\text{Lip}}\|f\|_{\text{Lip}}\|s-t\|,
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore we proved $T(h) f ∈ X$ with
$$
\left\|T(h) f\right\|_{\text{Lip}} ⩽ 3\|h\|_{\text{Lip}}\|f\|_{\text{Lip}} .
$$
So $
\left\|T(h)\right\| ⩽ 3\|h\|_{\text{Lip}}
$.
So $\left\|T\right\|⩽3$.
Take $h(x)=\|x\|$, then $\|h\|_{\text{Lip}}=1$ and $(T(h)f)(s)=f(s)\implies\|T(h)f\|_{\text{Lip}}=\|f\|_{\text{Lip}}\implies\left\|T\right\|⩾1$.
I don't know how to compute $\left\|T\right\|$ from here.

If I calculate correctly, the norm of $T$ is $3$, achieved by $h(x)=f(x)=x + |x - \frac{1}{2}| - |x + \frac{1}{2}|, s = \frac{1}{2}, t= \frac{1}{2} + \varepsilon$ and making $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ (i.e. the right derivative).

@Zerox Thanks. $$\lim _{x \to\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{+}}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\left(x+\left|x-\frac{1}{2}\right|-\left|x+\frac{1}{2}\right|\right)^2}{|x|}=-3$$so $|T|=3$. My question is solved.
